# Seeking a PyQt5 Widget for a Popup Window

Tags: qt, popup, pyqt5, popupwindow

I'm seeking a widget in PyQt5 to achieve the following effect. I would like to use a menu action, when clicked there is a popup window. However the active region of the popup window is constrained by the parent main window, i.e. I can drag-and-drop in the main window, but I cannot drag the popup window outside the frame of the main window.

I thought about it, and find that a simple customized dialog/sub-window cannot achieve the same thing (such window can be alive outside the parent window). Is there a widget in PyQt5 to make it happen?

Thank you.

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: Maybe [QMdiArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html#details)?

Comment: @user3419537 probably, let me try.